# how to say pretend in the context of a sentence

Tags: word-choice

How to say "pretend as if carrots tastes like chicken and eat it"

> 人参が鶏肉**ふり**をして食べて

or would

> 人参が鶏肉**まね**をして食べて

be better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What an unreasonable demand! :D But anyway...

> 鶏肉味の人参**だと思って**食べて
>
> 鶏肉の味がする人参**のつもりで**食べて

ふり and まね only work when someone changes their own behavior to display to others:

> 警官のまねをする *act as if one is (mock/play) a police officer*
>
> 気づかないふりをする *feign that one does not notice*

and not when you force yourself to feel something.

Comment: By "and not when you force yourself to feel something", what do u mean? 気づかないふりをする sounds to me like I'm forcing myself to feel something. Did you mean forcing someone else rather than myself to feel something?

Comment: @Newbie Oh I mean in a situation you actually notice it, but never tell or let others know that you do because you don't want to worry them or something. Not for deceiving yourself. Do you have any suggestion of less ambiguous English for this?

Comment: feigning ignorance perhaps. Just to be sure, まね and ふり cannot be used on 2nd person? (and third)

Comment: @Newbie (1) Thank you I'll take that. (2) Do you mean what I wrote "when you change your own behavior"? I intended the generic "you"...

Comment: I think I get it now. We can't use ふり for the carrot pretending to taste like meat. But we can use ふり if either "I" myself or "a 2nd person, for example: my friend (assuming I ask him to do it by saying 警官のまねをすて)"

Comment: @Newbie I rather say ふり is to make others believe that you are X, and what I explained is make yourself believe that you are X. Or did I make a wrong assumption? When I first looked at your example I visualized a scene parent talking to their child who doesn't eat vegetables, but if it's like an instruction to actor while taking a prank video or such, using ふり is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I see "pretend" represented by `振【ふ】りをする`.

The basic grammar rules are verb / i-adjective + `振【ふ】りをする`:

> 何【なに】も知【し】らない振【ふ】りをする。- Pretend you don't know anything.
>
> 気【き】持【も】ちを傷【きず】つけたくなかったから、おいしい振【ふ】りをした。- In order to not hurt his feelings, I pretended it tasted good.

Noun + の + 振【ふ】りをする:

> 彼【かれ】と会【あ】いたくなかったから、風邪【かぜ】の振【ふ】りをした。- I pretended to have a cold, because I didn't want to meet him.

Na-adjective + NA + 振【ふ】りをする:

> シャイな振【ふ】りをする。- To pretend you are shy.

"pretend as if carrots tastes like chicken and eat it":

> ニンジンが鶏【とり】肉【にく】のような味【あじ】がする振【ふ】りをして、食【た】べて。